# Aspose.Words Java, Low performance, long time for generate PDF from Word. After 2 days running the Application embedded

Tags: java, ms-word, pdf-generation, aspose, aspose.words

**When I restart the App Server (Mule 3.6.2), the time generation of PDF from Word is fine, it is around. 828.72ms,**

**Trace of execution:**

```
4   generateDocument(DMDocument)        828.72  CPU Total: 636.035 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   BuildDocumentComponent  Axcessfinancial -
5   <init>(InputStream)     75.34   CPU Total: 57.821 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms    Document    Aspose  -
6   <init>(zzXZ, int, int, boolean)     75.34   CPU Total: 57.821 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms    zzXZ    Aspose  -
5   replace(Pattern, String)        75.34   CPU Total: 57.821 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms    Range   Aspose  -
6   zzZ(Node[], boolean)        75.34   CPU Total: 57.821 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms    NodeCollection  Aspose  -
5   save(OutputStream, int)     678.04  CPU Total: 520.392 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   Document    Aspose  -
6   zzZ(boolean, char, StringBuilder)       75.34   CPU Total: 57.821 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms    zzYXN   Aspose  -
6   zzZzQ()     75.34   CPU Total: 57.821 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms    zzZMV   Aspose  -
6   zzM(zzWL)       75.34   CPU Total: 57.821 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms    zzZBL   Aspose  -
6   zzZ(zzZBL, long, int, boolean, boolean)     150.68  CPU Total: 115.643 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzZBL   Aspose  -
6   zzZfd()     75.34   CPU Total: 57.821 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms    SaveOptions Aspose  -
6   zzV(zzAV, zzAV)     75.34   CPU Total: 57.821 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms    zzAV    Asposewobfuscated   -
7   floatToRawIntBits(float)        75.34   CPU Total: 57.821 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms    Float   Asposewobfuscated   -
6   zzZ(zzA7, OutputStream)     150.68  CPU Total: 115.643 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zz8L    Asposewobfuscated   -
7   writeBytes(byte[], int, int, boolean)       150.68  CPU Total: 115.643 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   FileOutputStream    Asposewobfuscated   -
```

---

**After one-two days that Application running (avg 30000 pdfs generated), the time generation of PDF from Word is very High, it is around. 17264.77ms,**

**Trace of execution:**

```
4   generateDocument(DMDocument)        17264.77    CPU Total: 16,403.413 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms    BuildDocumentComponent  Axcessfinancial -
5   replace(Pattern, String)        152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   Range   Aspose  -
6   getParentStory()        152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   Paragraph   Aspose  -
5   save(OutputStream, int)     17111.98    CPU Total: 16,258.25 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms Document    Aspose  -
6   zzDW(int)       152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzZIW   Aspose  -
6   getNodeType()       152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   Paragraph   Aspose  -
6   getDocument()       152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   Node    Aspose  -
6   charAt(int)     152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   String  Aspose  -
6   zzUj(int)       152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzCX    Asposewobfuscated   -
7   zzV(char, int)      152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zz8R    Asposewobfuscated   -
6   currentThread()     152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   Thread  Aspose  -
6   zzUj(int)       305.57  CPU Total: 290.326 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzCX    Asposewobfuscated   -
7   zzV(char, int)      305.57  CPU Total: 290.326 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zz8R    Asposewobfuscated   -
6   get(int)        152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzFN    Asposewobfuscated   -
7   binarySearch(int[], int, int, int)      152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzZD    Asposewobfuscated   -
6   zzUj(int)       152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzCX    Asposewobfuscated   -
7   zzV(char, int)      152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zz8R    Asposewobfuscated   -
6   getNodeType()       152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   Row Aspose  -
6   zzZ(zzZBL, zzZBL, zzZBL, boolean)       152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzZPF   Aspose  -
6   zzu(boolean)        152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzVB    Asposewobfuscated   -
6   zzN(zzZ2O)      152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzZOJ   Aspose  -
6   zzZay()     152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzZ2O   Aspose  -
6   zz1y()      305.57  CPU Total: 290.326 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zz9Z    Aspose  -
6   zzxv()      152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzZOA   Aspose  -
6   zzqY()      152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzZBL   Aspose  -
6   zzZC0()     152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzZN6   Aspose  -
6   zzx7()      152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzZ17   Aspose  -
6   zzZag()     152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzZ2O   Aspose  -
6   zzZaq()     152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzZ2O   Aspose  -
6   zzZFg()     152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzZO9   Aspose  -
6   zzY(zzZ2O, zzZ2O)       152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzZOA   Aspose  -
6   zzZag()     152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzZ2O   Aspose  -
6   zzXR(int, int)      152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzZ2O   Aspose  -
6   zzt(boolean)        152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzVB    Asposewobfuscated   -
7   zzv(boolean)        152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzVB    Asposewobfuscated   -
6   zzxv()      152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzZOA   Aspose  -
6   zzZaL()     305.57  CPU Total: 290.326 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzZ2O   Aspose  -
7   zzZzW()     152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzZMV   Aspose  -
6   zzZak()     152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzZ2O   Aspose  -
6   zzZac()     152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzZ2O   Aspose  -
6   getPosition()       152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzZMV   Aspose  -
6   zzx6()      152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzZBL   Aspose  -
6   zzpK()      152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzZ1P   Aspose  -
6   zzZay()     152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzZ2O   Aspose  -
6   zzZaa()     152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzZ2O   Aspose  -
6   zz0R()      152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzZ1L   Aspose  -
6   zzVa(boolean)       152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzZN0   Aspose  -
6   zzqY()      152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzZBL   Aspose  -
6   getLineStyle()      152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzZN6   Aspose  -
6   zzZEf()     152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzZOB   Aspose  -
6   zzZDK()     4430.78 CPU Total: 4,209.726 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms zzZOA   Aspose  -
7   zzZac()     152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzZ2O   Aspose  -
7   zzZAX()     152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzZN0   Aspose  -
7   zzxv()      152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzZOA   Aspose  -
7   zzZag()     152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzZ2O   Aspose  -
7   zzZA0()     152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzZMV   Aspose  -
7   zzu(boolean)        152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzVB    Asposewobfuscated   -
8   zzZX(double)        152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzOJ    Asposewobfuscated   -
7   zzxY(int)       152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzZ1K   Aspose  -
7   zzZav()     152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzZ2O   Aspose  -
7   zzZac()     152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzZ2O   Aspose  -
7   zzqY()      152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzZBL   Aspose  -
7   zzZau()     152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzZ2O   Aspose  -
7   zzZBS()     152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzZN0   Aspose  -
7   zzxv()      152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zz04    Aspose  -
7   zzSa(boolean)       305.57  CPU Total: 290.326 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzZ2O   Aspose  -
8   zzZzR()     152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzZMV   Aspose  -
7   zzx5()      152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zz2 Aspose  -
7   zz0R()      152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzZ20   Aspose  -
7   zzZac()     152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzZ2O   Aspose  -
7   zzZaq()     152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzZ2O   Aspose  -
7   zzr(boolean)        152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzVB    Asposewobfuscated   -
8   zzs(boolean)        152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzVB    Asposewobfuscated   -
7   zzZaq()     152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzZ2O   Aspose  -
7   zzZnt()     152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzZ2O   Aspose  -
7   zzZGd()     152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzZPF   Aspose  -
7   getWidth()      152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzZ2O   Aspose  -
7   zzA(int, boolean)       152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zz9Z    Aspose  -
7   zzZDH()     152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzZOA   Aspose  -
7   zz0R()      152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzZ1L   Aspose  -
7   zzZaa()     152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzZ2O   Aspose  -
6   zzup()      152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzZC3   Aspose  -
6   zzZaq()     152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzZ2O   Aspose  -
6   zzx5()      152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zz2 Aspose  -
6   zzZGd()     152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzZPF   Aspose  -
6   zzY(zzZ2O, zzZ2O)       152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzZOA   Aspose  -
6   zzr(boolean)        152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzVB    Asposewobfuscated   -
6   zzZBS()     152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzZN0   Aspose  -
6   zzr(boolean)        152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzVB    Asposewobfuscated   -
7   zzs(boolean)        152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzVB    Asposewobfuscated   -
6   zzZDQ()     152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzZ2O   Aspose  -
6   zzxv()      305.57  CPU Total: 290.326 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzZOA   Aspose  -
6   zzZaV()     152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzZ1L   Aspose  -
6   zzZaq()     152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzZ2O   Aspose  -
6   zzr(boolean)        152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzVB    Asposewobfuscated   -
7   zzo(double)     152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzWR    Asposewobfuscated   -
6   zzZ(zzZOB)      152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzZOJ   Aspose  -
6   zzr(boolean)        152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzVB    Asposewobfuscated   -
7   zzZX(double)        152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzOJ    Asposewobfuscated   -
6   zzZag()     152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzZ2O   Aspose  -
6   zzZaV()     152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzZ1L   Aspose  -
6   zzqY()      152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzZBL   Aspose  -
6   zzZau()     152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzZ2O   Aspose  -
6   zzW(zzAW)       152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzG5    Asposewobfuscated   -
7   setCapacity(int)        152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzG5    Asposewobfuscated   -
6   getWidth()      152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzZ2O   Aspose  -
6   zzZaS()     152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzZ2O   Aspose  -
6   getNode()       152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zz9X    Aspose  -
6   zzxv()      152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzZP7   Aspose  -
6   zzL(float, float)       152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzAO    Asposewobfuscated   -
7   floatToRawIntBits(float)        152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   Float   Asposewobfuscated   -
6   zzN(zzZU)       152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzI5    Asposewobfuscated   -
7   zzZ(zzVB, zzJ5)     152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzJW    Asposewobfuscated   -
6   zzqY()      152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzZBL   Aspose  -
6   zzZ8w()     152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzZ1G   Aspose  -
6   zzxv()      152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzZP7   Aspose  -
6   <init>(zzVB, zzVF, zzVF, long, String, long, float, boolean, boolean)       152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zz0 Asposewobfuscated   -
7   zzV(char, int)      152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zz8R    Asposewobfuscated   -
6   zzxv()      152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzZP7   Aspose  -
6   zzxv()      152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzZP7   Aspose  -
6   zzyb(int)       152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzZ2O   Aspose  -
6   zzN(zzZU)       611.14  CPU Total: 580.652 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzI5    Asposewobfuscated   -
7   write(String)       152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzHE    Asposewobfuscated   -
7   next()      152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzFB    Asposewobfuscated   -
7   <init>(int)     152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzY7    Asposewobfuscated   -
7   toArray()       152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzY7    Asposewobfuscated   -
6   endDocument()       152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zzI5    Asposewobfuscated   -
7   arraycopy(Object, int, Object, int, int)        152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   System  Asposewobfuscated   -
6   zzZ(zzA7, OutputStream)     152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   zz8L    Asposewobfuscated   -
7   writeBytes(byte[], int, int, boolean)       152.79  CPU Total: 145.163 ms, Sync Total: 0 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension Total: 0 ms   FileOutputStream    Asposewobfuscated   -
```

**Is there any settings to prevent this poor performance ?.** Or is it a bug of Api Aspose.

Comment: SO is a forum to present code and ask questions, for us to assist. The above is not even a question. It is a statement.

Comment: Add the question, to clarify the post.

Comment: The thread opened in Aspose forum is: http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/thread/670618/low-performance-long-time-for-generate-pdf-from-word.after-2-days-running-the-application-embedded.aspx

Comment: It is to remind you that Aspose.Words' team is waiting for your further input to investigate this issue. As requested [here](http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/permalink/670618/671184/showthread.aspx#671184) in Aspose.Words forum, please provide your input Word document(s) and Java application to be able to reproduce this issue on our end and fix it. I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.